# PDE with a non-classical boundary condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, linear-pde, parabolic-pde

Assume that one has a classical PDE, say: $u_t(t,x)-u_{xx}(t,x)=0$, $t\in (0,1)$, $x\in (0,2)$, and $u(0,x)=0$. Then we can prove existence (and uniqueness) of solution when boundary conditions: $u(t,0)=f(t)$, $u(t,2)=g(t)$ are prescribed.

My question: what if one replaces the first bc by $u(t,\color{red}{1})=f(t)$? How can we prove existence in this case?

Is there any way to get back to the usual bcs?

**Edit:**
What if one considers instead $u(t,0)=u(t,\color{red}{1})=f(t)$ while keeping the second bc at $x=2$?

Comment: You can solve uniquely on $(1, 2)$, this gives you $u_x(t,1)$, so on $(0, 1)$ you are left with the question of finding a solution $u$ when $u(t, 1)$ and $u_x(t, 1)$ are known. Searching the words "lateral Cauchy problem" may help for this.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I've had a look at "lateral Cauchy problem" but did't find an existence result (only some uniqueness)

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: You cannot prescribe $u(t, 0), u(t, 1)$ and $u(t, 2)$ because the Dirichlet problem on $(0,1)$ gives a unique solution, the Dirichlet problem on $(1,2)$ gives a unique solution and these two solutions will not generally have the same normal derivative $u_x(t, 1)$ to produce a solution of the heat equation on $(0,2)$. Why do you want to do this?